# MS Bot Framework - test, strings, triggers, intentdialogs, translation

Tags: botframework

1. Is it possible to test the bot using predefined conversations?
2. How exactly does `session.gettext()` look for strings across libraries? Is it possible to call the same answers from multiple libraries?
3. Does `bot.dialog.cancelAction` trigger in child dialogs as well? It didn’t always work for us - is it possible to combine this with IntentDialogs at all or do IntentDialogs always override any global triggers?
4. For Czech and Slovak, we always translate incoming messages to English and send them to LUIS; however, can we also send them untranslated to a Q&A maker knowledge base?
5. How do we translate outgoing messages to the correct language when we haven't got access to `session` in `IMiddlewareMap.send`?

Comment: Please avoid asking several questions inside 1 StackOverflow questions

Comment: 1.- You can create unit tests for your bot and simulate conversations: https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/01/20/unit-testing-for-bot-applications/ 4.- You can either have your KB in multiple languages or translate back and from English to the destination language. I have a sample that deal with translating with multiple languages with QnAMaker using only one KB https://github.com/FranciscoPonceGomez/QnATranslatorSample